# iOS PDFView selectAll and currentSelection doesn't select text visually

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, pdfview

I'm trying to highlight a word (with Copy, Find, Translate buttons) by single tap in PDFView.
Like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz6bQ.jpg)

It is easy to identify the word that was tapped thanks to the [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfpage/1503502-selectionforword).

But then when I set `selection` to `pdfView.currentSelection` visually nothing happens. And this happens until I make a classic long tap on the text, which seems to "activate" the visual highlighting function. Then any setting `pdfView.currentSelection` displays selection.

Everything is the same with `pdfView.selectAll(nil)`

The problem is very similar to the problem with UITextView - but there is [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708608/uitextview-selectedrange-not-displaying-when-set-programmatically) with `textView.select(self)` call before set `selectedRange`

if you try to call the method you will get a crash `-[PDFView select:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x105d0d120`

You can try this code and you will see that the text is selected (in `selectionChangeNotification`), but visually nothing happens.
But if you increase Dispatch interval and you will have time to select the text (word) with a long tap you will see how all the text is selected after `asyncAfter` firing.

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var pdfView: PDFView?
        
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "somePDF", withExtension: "pdf") else {
            return
        }
        
        let pdfView = PDFView()

        pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(pdfView)
        pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        if let document = PDFDocument(url: path) {
            pdfView.document = document
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(selectionChangeNotification),
            name: .PDFViewSelectionChanged,
            object: pdfView
        )
        self.pdfView = pdfView
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
            self.pdfView?.selectAll(nil)
        }
    }
    
    @objc
    private func selectionChangeNotification() {
        print(pdfView?.currentSelection)
    }
}
```

**UPD:**

I checked on iOS 15.7.6 and it works. On iOS 17 doesn't.

**UPD 2:**

On iOS 16.4 (simulator) this also works.